# How to correctly search models with a join table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to set up my models and controllers for a user event setup. It's a many-to-many setup for users to sign up for events. I already have the join table ('users_events') created.

So far I have:

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :events, join_table: 'users_events'
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: 'users_events'
end
```

I want to be able to be able to query for all events a user is signed up for. Where should this query go? In users_controller or events_controller? What would the search/find code look like?

Comment: you can simply do a `User.first.events` to get all user events and no need to define `, join_table: 'users_events'` rails by convention can automatically map that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. As I elaborated in my reply to Nikolai, I also have a one-to-many relationship in that an event belongs_to (was created by) a user, so user.events was giving me  the events the user had created, not what they were attending. Here is how I solved it.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
    has_and_belongs_to_many :attending_events, class_name: 'Event'
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_and_belongs_to_many :attendees, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all users_events goes against rails convention. Rails infers table names by alphabetical order so the table should be named: events_users

Then you can do things like:

```
      current_user.events
```

Or

```
     event = Event.create!(name: "foo")
     current_user.events << event
```

And the other way around..this way you also don't need to mention the join table in your model.

Comment: Just an example. (As in pseudo code). Can do User.first << event or user = current_user (if defined by devise or other way) and then user.events << event

Comment: Or users = User.all; event = Event.create!(name: "foo") and then users.each do |u| u.events << event end

Comment: I guess I assumed that an event which has many participants is being created no matter what or you would probably create a user who has many events and then it would be unique to a user :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on alphabetical order on the join table, I didn't know that. I should have been more thorough in what I have. These models also have a one-to-many relationship in that an event `belongs_to :user` and a user `has_many :events`. This is to indicate who created the event, so `current_user.events` gives me the events the user created, not the ones they signed up for.

Comment: @Nikolai Manek: please edit the answer instead of commenting.